# Post request works in postman but not in my code

Tags: angular, http

**reg.ts**

```
var data = JSON.stringify({
  "name": {
    "value": this.registerForm.value.email
  },
  "mail": {
    "value": this.registerForm.value.email
  },
  "pass": {
    "value": this.registerForm.value.password
  },
  "field_user_type": {
    "value": 'normal' // |  venue|celebrity|event_management//this.userType
  }
  });

  let header=new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  header.append("cache-control", "no-cache");

  this.http.post('..................../user/register? 
  _format=json',data, {headers: header}).
   subscribe(res=>{
   this.output=res.json()
   if(this.output) {
     this.navCtrl.setRoot(AgreementPage)
   }
  },
  err=>{
   console.log(err)
   })
```

I can send post with postman,and getting the response successfully,but   When i make a post request as shown above getting error message

> "X-CSRF-Token request header is missing"

Comment: can you share backend code and used technology?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in your middleware. It is caused by the [Cross-site request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) defense [measures](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)).

So you either need a specific token in the header, Or, disable CORS check in the middleware.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to create RequestOptions object. Instead of direct passing headers try to create an object and pass it into post method parameter

```js
let header = new Headers({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
});
header.append("cache-control", "no-cache");
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: header });

this.http.post('..................../user/register? 
    _format = json ',data, options).
    subscribe(res => {
        this.output = res.json()
        if (this.output) {
          this.navCtrl.setRoot(AgreementPage)
        }
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err)
      })
```